# Why is this insert not working?`

Tags: c#, oracle10g

Actually my code was suppose to check that is there any value in the `course_choice_teacher` table. If there is not, then it will insert some values into the table. Now this time there is no value in the table. So `dr2.Read()` should return false and do the else portion. But it is doing the reverse thing. I'll be very happy if you help me in this purpose.

```
string oradb = "Data Source=localhost;User Id=system;Password=cse;";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
conn.Open();

OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand();
cmd2.Connection = conn;
cmd2.CommandText = "select * from course_choice_teacher where teacher_id='"+teacher_home.st+"' and choice_no=1";
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

OracleDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

if (dr2.Read())
{
   MessageBox.Show("Already Given");
}
else
{
   OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
   cmd.Connection = conn;
   cmd.CommandText = "insert into course_choice_teacher values('" + teacher_home.st + "','" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["course_id"].Value.ToString() + "',1)";
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

   OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   dr.Read();
}

conn.Dispose();
```

Comment: Maybe my eyes deceive me, but where is the Database name specified? I haven't touched Oracle in a while, but usually ConnectionStrings have the name of the Database in them.

Answer (score 0):

The datareader has property .HasRows to check if the result has some rows. This would be a proper way to check what you intend to do.

```
if (dr2.HasRows)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Already Given");
}
else
{
  .........
}
```

Comment: Another way to achieve it would be to do a query for count(*) and check the return result as you are not doing anything with the result received from select *